# Vim line numbers in insert mode

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

For some reason, Vim (gVim for Windows) turns off the line numbers when I enter insert mode.
This can be rather jarring, because it shifts all the code to the right or left when I leave or enter insert mode - and I do this quite often.

Any ideas to how to keep line numbers (relativenumber, to be exact) on regardless of mode.

Key:
[] : cursor
|  : cursor in insert mode

Normal mode

```
2 for(i = 0; i < something; i++) {
1    // some code here
0    // I am her[e]
1    // some more code
```

Insert mode

```
for(i = 0; i < something; i++) {
   // some code here
   // I am her|e
   // some more code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like some script or plugin somewhere is trying to be helpful.  You can probably determine what it is with this command:

```
 :verbose autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave
```

This should list the events defined and the files that defined them.  What you do at that point depends on whether you want to keep the script/plugin and just configure/modify it, or remove it entirely.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for this. I'll look into the offending plugin to see what the deal is (looks to be numbers.vim)